# Collatz series function not calculating for third process

Tags: c, linux, memory, process

Hi I'm fairly new to Linux C and and the whole shared memory and multiple process concept. The program below is a Collatz sequence/series. The first two processes calculate the right amount of steps and put them into the shared memory the third process P3 doesn't seem to calculate it right or put it into the memory (that's what I think is happening at least). If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong this I'd really appreciate it. Thanks (any resources for learning Linux C would be appreciated as well).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MICRO_SEC_IN_SEC 1000000


struct sharedMem
{
    int C[3];
    int S[3];
};

int main(void)
{
    pid_t P1, P2, P3;

    struct sharedMem *sharedMemory;
    struct timeval start, end;
    int n = 25;
    void *shared_memory = (void *)0;
    

    int min;
    int max;
    int avg;

    int shmId = shmget((key_t)1253, sizeof(struct sharedMem), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    
    if (shmId == - 1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmget failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shared_memory = shmat(shmId, (void *)0, 0);

    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sharedMemory = (struct sharedMem *)shared_memory;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        sharedMemory->S[i] = 0;
    }

    sharedMemory->C[0] = n;
    sharedMemory->C[1] = n*2;
    sharedMemory->C[2] = n*3;

    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    P1 = fork();

    switch (P1)
    {

    case -1:
        perror("Fork failed\n");
        exit(1);

    case 0:
        printf("Child Process: working with Collatz function %d\n", sharedMemory->C[0]);
        
        while (sharedMemory->C[0] != 1)
        {
            if(sharedMemory->C[0] % 2 == 0)
            {
                sharedMemory->C[0] /= 2;
            }
            else
            {
                sharedMemory->C[0] = 3 * sharedMemory->C[0] + 1;
            }
            sharedMemory->S[0]++;
        }
        break;

    default:
        P2 = fork();

        switch (P2)
        {

        case -1:
            perror("Fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        
        case 0:
            printf("Child Process: working with Collatz function %d\n", sharedMemory->C[1]);

            while (sharedMemory->C[1] != 1)
            {
                if(sharedMemory->C[1] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sharedMemory->C[1] /= 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    sharedMemory->C[1] = 3 * sharedMemory->C[1] + 1;
                }
                sharedMemory->S[1]++;
            }
            break;

        default:
            P3 = fork();

            switch (P3)
            {

            case -1:
                perror("Fork failed\n");
                exit(1);
            
            case 0:
                printf("Child Process: working with Collatz function %d\n", sharedMemory->C[2]);

                while (sharedMemory->C[2] != 1)
                {
                    if(sharedMemory->C[2] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        sharedMemory->C[2] /= 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sharedMemory->C[2] = 3 * sharedMemory->C[2] + 1;
                    }
                    sharedMemory->S[2]++;
                }
                printf("\n%d\n",sharedMemory->S[2]);
                wait();
            break;

            default:
                wait();
                wait();
                wait();

                gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

                printf("\n%d\n",sharedMemory->S[0]);
                printf("\n%d\n",sharedMemory->S[1]);
                printf("\n%d\n",sharedMemory->S[2]);

                avg = (sharedMemory->S[0] + sharedMemory->S[1] + sharedMemory->S[2]) / 3;

                min = sharedMemory->S[0];
                max = sharedMemory->S[0];

                for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    if(sharedMemory->S[i] < min)
                    {
                        min = sharedMemory->S[i];
                    }
                    else if(sharedMemory->S[i] > max)
                    {
                        max = sharedMemory->S[i];
                    }
                }
                printf("Average: %d\nMinama: %d\nMaxama: %d\n",avg,min,max);

                printf("Start Time: %lf sec from Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 + 0000 (UTC))\n",start.tv_sec + (double)start.tv_usec/MICRO_SEC_IN_SEC);

                printf("End Time: %lf sec from Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 + 0000 (UTC))\n",start.tv_sec + (double)start.tv_usec/MICRO_SEC_IN_SEC);

                printf("Elapsed Time: %ld micro sec\n",((end.tv_sec * MICRO_SEC_IN_SEC + end.tv_usec)-(start.tv_sec * MICRO_SEC_IN_SEC + start.tv_usec)));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Aside: the sequence can go out of range of `int` depending on the starting value. So the working value and `max` should be 64-bit if the starting value is 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 2):

> You used `sharedMemory->S[2]` but never initialized it.

I'm not familiar with Coltaz function, but it seems you have a mistake in initialization. To initialize *S* array with three member change `i < 2` to `i < 3` .

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sharedMemory->S[i] = 0;
    }
```